# Split a IObservable<(long,float)> into two observables of IObservable<long> and IObservable<float>

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream (hot observable)  of type `IObservable<(long, float)>` and would like to split it into two observables of `IObservable<long>` and `IObservable<float>`

I have naively tried the following but I only get `flowStream` populated.

```cs
IObservable<long pressure, float flow> sourceHotObservable = GetStream(); 

var pressureStream = sourceHotObservable.Select(i => i.pressure);
var flowStream = sourceHotObservable.Select(i => i.flow);
```

Comment: i am sorry, that is exactly code you used?

Comment: You could try using a KeyValuePair<long, float> or even a simple custom class with `pressure` and `flow` auto-implemented properties and a constructor.

Comment: Looks fine except you can just do 'var sourceHotObservable = GetStream()' If I were to guess, your problem is actually inside of GetStream. Debug in there and take a look at what value it's assigning to your pressure.

Comment: @SteffenColeBlake I would agree with you. Let me have a look at it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code seems to work fine.

If I try this:

```
var sourceHotObservable = Observable.Return((pressure: 1L, flow: 3.0f)).Publish();

var pressureStream = sourceHotObservable.Select(i => i.pressure);
var flowStream = sourceHotObservable.Select(i => i.flow);

pressureStream.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
flowStream.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

sourceHotObservable.Connect();
```

I get :

```
1
3
```

Comment: @resp78 - Yes, totally agree. It must be.

Comment: @resp78 - I suspect that the stream needs to be published.

Comment: Enigmativity...your code could confuse slightly... "Observbale.Return" is not a HOT observable. By definition, it is a cold one. If you call it twice, it reutrns twice. It doesn't need to be shared. Therefore, your sample will always work, but the 'GetStream()' used by the poster is probably hot, which is why their 2nd subscription is missing the update. As you write later though, the answer almost certianly is to Publish() and share the stream. I'm just not a fan of code like this:  "var sourceHotObservable = Observable.Return"

Comment: @H_Andr - Fair enough. Though a hot observable with two subscriptions should still return values for each observer.

Answer (score 0):

You have not showed us in your snippet how you subscribe to the streams - you have only shown us the intermediate .Select() statements.
However, I suspect that you are later on calling .Subscribe on each of these, and that your stream is made Hot by the first subscription, causing the 2nd one to miss the update.

Try this instead:

```
IObservable<long pressure, float flow> sourceHotObservable = GetStream().Publish();
```

... then after your subscribe code...

`sourceHotObservable.Connect(); //be sure to manage lifetime of returned disposable`

Enigmativity replied with an answer which shows the code to work correctly, but his use of Observable.Return(), is actually a cold stream. This means each subscribe would get a new Observable with the item returned, so it may not be an accurate representation of your own scenario. If your stream is made hot by your first subscribe, you could well miss the item in the 2nd subscribe.

Let us know.

Comment: The mistake I made whilst implementing the `GetStream` (hot observable) was that I overwrote the first subscription when the second call to Select was made.